# DataGridView select multiple row, check each row

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010, multi-select

I am trying to select all rows by a button or select different rows with ctrl+click. 
But even if I have selected multiple rows, it only checks the first row. Then it rereads it again instead of going to the next row.
I'm not sure either where to put the multiselect code.

Originally, you're only supposed to just click a row then check if conditions are satisfied. However it was requested that you can do multiple and check each row if condition is satisfied.

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    _subjectno = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
    _title = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
    _unit = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
    _pre = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    DataGridView1.MultiSelect = True
    DataGridView1.SelectAll()
End Sub



Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim selectedItems As DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection = DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In selectedItems
        add()
    Next
End Sub



Sub add()
    Try

        If IS_EMPTY(txtSno) = True Then Return

        cm = New MySqlCommand("select * from tblenroll where subjectnumber like '" & _subjectno & "' and remarks <> 'Failed' and studentno like '" & txtSno.Text & "'", cn)
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            MsgBox("Subject is already taken.", vbExclamation)
            dr.Close()
            Return
        Else
            dr.Close()
        End If

        If _pre = "NONE" Or _pre = "2ND YR STANDING" Or _pre = "3RD YR STANDING" Or _pre = "4TH YR STANDING" Or _pre = "5TH YR STANDING" Then

            cm = New MySqlCommand("insert into tblenroll (studentno, subjectnumber, ay,semester,dateenrolled, curriculum) values ('" & txtSno.Text & "','" & _subjectno & "','" & txtAY.Text & "','" & txtSem.Text & "','" & Now & "','" & txtCurriculum.Text & "')", cn)
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox(_subjectno & " successfully added.", vbInformation)
            LoadEnrolled()
        Else

            cm = New MySqlCommand("select * from tblenroll where studentno like '" & txtSno.Text & "' and subjectnumber like '" & _subjectno & "' and ay like '" & txtAY.Text & "'", cn)
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader
            dr.Read()
            If dr.HasRows Then
                MsgBox("Subject is already taken.", vbExclamation)
                dr.Close()
                Return
            Else
                dr.Close()
            End If


            Dim strok As Boolean = False

            Dim strArr() As String
            Dim count As Integer
            Dim strpre As String = _pre
            strArr = strpre.Split(", ")
            For count = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
                cm = New MySqlCommand("select * from tblenroll as e inner join tblsubject as s on e.subjectnumber = s.subjectno where s.subjectno like '%" & Trim(strArr(count)) & "%' and studentno like '" & txtSno.Text & "' and remarks like 'Passed'", cn)
                dr = cm.ExecuteReader
                dr.Read()
                If dr.HasRows Then
                    dr.Close()
                    strok = True
                Else
                    MsgBox("Unable to enroll this subject. Pre-requisite " & strArr(count) & ".", vbExclamation)
                    dr.Close()
                    Return
                End If
            Next


            If strok = True Then
                cm = New MySqlCommand("insert into tblenroll (studentno, subjectnumber, ay, semester, dateenrolled, curriculum) values ('" & txtSno.Text & "','" & _subjectno & "','" & txtAY.Text & "','" & txtSem.Text & "','" & Now & "','" & txtCurriculum.Text & "')", cn)
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox(_subjectno & " successfully added.", vbInformation)
                LoadEnrolled()
            End If
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Make `_subjectno`, `_title`, `_unit`, `_pre` parameters of your `Add` method, and make them local variables that are set in your `Button2_Click` event handler.

Comment: Copy all of what's in DataGridView1_SelectionChanged to inside your loop in Button2_Click right before the `add()` line.

Comment: @MrGadget I've tried, but it still keeps on staying on the first row index. A messagebox repeatedly shows "Subject is already taken"

Comment: @SSS it still repeatedly checks the first row

Comment: Please update your post with the code as I've described...let's see where you've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
        _subjectno = selectedItem.Cells(0).Value
        _title = selectedItem.Cells(1).Value
        _unit = selectedItem.Cells(2).Value
        _pre = selectedItem.Cells(3).Value
        add()
    Next
End Sub
```